# Last records from WadLogsTable

Tags: azure, azure-storage

How can i get the last 100 records from the WADLogsTable Ordered by date ?

I tried to do it with this piece of code but it doesn't work

```
                var query = (from entity in tsc.CreateQuery<LogsObject>("WADLogsTable")
                        where entity.PartitionKey.CompareTo(startTime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks.ToString("D19")) >= 0
                        orderby entity.EventTickCount descending
                        select entity);
```

Where tsc is the TableServiceContext.

I can get the records but i'm interested in the recents logs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Azure table storage doesn't support sorting, so entities always come back sorted by their PartitionKey+RowKey. But I suspect the log entries are already in reverse chronological order. Aren't they?

[**EDIT**] Apparently they're not. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your post. the log entries is not in reverse chronogical order.

Comment: As pointed out by Steve, currently table storage doesn't support sorting. If your entries are not in reverse chronogical order, you have to first download the entries to your local machine and then do a sort locally. You may want to submit a feature suggestion on http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ATCommon.DiagnosticConfig);
    CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    TableServiceContext serviceContext = cloudTableClient.GetDataServiceContext();
    IQueryable<WadLogEntity> traceLogsTable = serviceContext.CreateQuery<WadLogEntity>("WADLogsTable");
    var selection = from row in traceLogsTable where row.PartitionKey.CompareTo("0" + DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(hours).Ticks) >= 0 select row;
    //var selection = from row in traceLogsTable where row.PartitionKey.CompareTo("0" + DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5.0).Ticks) >= 0 select row;
    CloudTableQuery<WadLogEntity> query = selection.AsTableServiceQuery<WadLogEntity>();
    IEnumerable<WadLogEntity> output = query.Execute();
 return output.OrderByDescending(s => s.Timestamp).Take(100).ToList();
```